# How do I resolve this decimal Regex for 1-24 and precisions of 2 between 0 and 23

Tags: javascript, regex

`^((([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])?\b([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\b(\.\d\d?)?))|((([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])?\b([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])\b(\.\d?)?))|(2[0-4])$`

I want to do everything from 1-24 and any precision of 2 if it is between 0 and 23.

I can't seem to get the following types to be excluded:

`0.5`
`0.2`

**Acceptance:**

1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18,
19,
20,
21,
22,
23,
24

2.22, 2.01

2.1

**Fail**

0.5, 0.9, 25, 25.01, 24.01, 24.89

**EDIT**

I need this to be supported in JS.

Comment: Can you give several examples which will match (and which will not match)?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to validate decimal ranges.

Comment: @alfasin What would be a better way to approach this?

Comment: Check if it's a number between 1-24 and use formatting/rounding to two digits after the dot.

Comment: @alfasin yeah, I was doing that, but there was an additional use case where I need to validate precision.  I am having an issue only getting the numbers between 0 and 1.  I want to avoid matching those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match anything from `1` to `24` allowing upto 2 optional decimal points:

```
/^((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|24)$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/eT9bR5/1)

Or without using anchors you can use:

```
/(?:^|[^.])\b((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|24)\b(?!\.\d+)/g
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/eT9bR5/2)

Comment: This still has my issues and does not cover 10-24.

Comment: The next edit fixes my issue, but it doesn't solve my issues with numbers less than 1.

Comment: I'm testing this in http://regexpal.com/ and it misses 10, 20, and still has 0.5.

Comment: You're not testing it right as you can see in above demo link. It matches `10` and doesn't match `0.5`. Are you sure you copied latest regex from above with `gm` flags?

Comment: Yep, I'm using a JS tester because its for Javascript.  Here's another version I can share:  http://regexr.com/3alum

Comment: Did you check demo link I provided or tried this regex in JSFiddle?

Comment: Looks like this works fine. Thanks!  Maybe I made mistake on the tool.

Comment: Yes you didn't have `multiline` flag selected in your regex. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use this regex:

`\b([2][0-3]|[1][0-9]|(?<![0-9.])[1-9]|24(?!\.))(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?\b`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE1sU1/2).

Comment: Then, there is *no* way to do it in 1 step/with just 1 regex in JS. You will either need to use `([2][0-3]|[1][0-9]|(?:\b)[1-9]\b|24(?!\.))(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` and then re-check the output with `^0(\.[0-9]+)?$` regex, or split out all the numbers, and then test them one by one with anubhava's suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This works for all your test cases:

```
(((?<=^)|(?<=\s))([13-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])|(?<=\D)2(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)(?=[^\d.]|$)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/7jMLkLnmCm)